# How to use Pattern Matching on a collection

Tags: f#

**Can I use pattern matching on a collection?**

I have a grid that represents a tic-tac-toe board.

How can I use pattern matching to identify streaks of either 'X' or 'O'?

So far I built a grid like this:

```
// ----------------
//  0 |  1  |  2  |
// ----------------
//  3 |  4  |  5  |
// ----------------
//  6 |  7  |  8  |
// ----------------

type Marker =
| X = 0
| O = 1
| NULL = 3

let cells = [0..8]
let grid = [for cell in cells -> (cell, Marker.NULL)]

let streakExists = 
   match grid with
   | ???
   | ???
```

So I want to use pattern matching to identify a streak like the following:

// if grid.[..2] all have X

// or grid.[3..5] all have X

// or grid.[6..8] all have X

//  return true

//-----------------

// if grid.[0;3;6;] all have X

// or grid.[1;4;5] all have X

// or grid.[2;5;8] all have X

//   return true

//------------------

// if grid.[0;4;8;] all have X

//   return true

**NOTE:**

I am learning the basics of F#.
As a result please forgive me if this question appears obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern matching on collections, but there are quite a lot of cases in that you would have to cover in tic-tac-toe, so it is probably not the best option.

If I simplify your code a bit (to use a discriminated union rather then enum and to use just a list of values of the discriminated union), it would look like this:

```
type Marker =
  | X
  | O
  | NULL 

let grid = [ for cell in 0 .. 8 -> NULL ]

let streakExists = 
   match grid with
   | [X;X;X;_;_;_;_;_;_] 
   | [_;_;_;X;X;X;_;_;_] 
   | [_;_;_;_;_;_;X;X;X] -> "X wins"
   | _ -> "Not sure"
```

This would work, but you can see how hard it will be to cover all cases. If I wanted to solve the same problem, I would probably write it differently. You could create a list of lists that represent all possible streaks in the grid:

```
let streaks = 
  [ for row in [0;3;6] do      // Generate one streak for each row
      yield [row;row+1;row+2]
    for col in [0;1;2] do      // Generate one streak for each column
      yield [col;col+3;col+6]
    yield [0;4;8]              // Explicitly add two 
    yield [2;4;6] ]            // diagonal streaks
```

Now you could check if `grid` contains a winning streak by testing whether there is any streak (from `streaks`) such that values at all the specified indices are `X` or `O`. This should be easy to do with `List.forall` and `List.exists`.

Answer (score 2):

As Tomas wrote, it'd be easier to simplify the `Marker` type to a Discriminated Union:

```
type Marker = X | O | NULL
```

Also, since the board is so small, you can just keep it as a list of eight values:

```
let grid = List.init 8 (fun _ -> NULL)
```

I agree with Tomas that pattern matching probably isn't the best way to address this problem, but for completeness' sake, you *can* make matches that somewhat visibly communicate the patterns they match on:

```
let hasStreak = function
    | [X; X; X;
       _; _; _;
       _; _; _]
    | [_; _; _;
       X; X; X;
       _; _; _]
    | [_; _; _;
       _; _; _;
       X; X; X]
    | [X; _; _;
       X; _; _;
       X; _; _]
    | [_; X; _;
       _; X; _;
       _; X; _]
    | [_; _; X;
       _; _; X;
       _; _; X]
    | [X; _; _;
       _; X; _;
       _; _; X]
    | [_; _; X;
       _; X; _;
       X; _; _] -> true
    // The same sort of cases should go here for O...
    | _ -> false
```

Comment: I can't just use a parameter for hasStreak instead? Then I can define the pattern just once instead of both 'X' and 'O'. No? let hadStreak m = function | [m;m;m;_;_;_:_;_;_]

Answer (score 1):

If you pattern match directly to the grid, I'm not sure the syntax is going to be very nice, your options are:

```
let streakExists grid =
    match grid with
    |[Marker.X; Marker.X; Marker.X; _; _; _; _; _; _] -> true
    |[_; _; _; Marker.X; Marker.X; Marker.X; _; _; _] -> true
    |[_; _; _; _; _; _; Marker.X; Marker.X; Marker.X] -> true
     ...
    | _ -> false
```

or

```
let streakExists grid =
    match grid with
    |Marker.X :: Marker.X :: Marker.X :: _ -> true
    | _ :: _ :: _ :: Marker.X :: Marker.X :: Marker.X :: _ -> true
    | _ :: _ :: _ :: _ :: _ :: _ :: Marker.X :: Marker.X :: Marker.X :: []  -> true
     ...
    | _ -> false
```

(this option isn't ideal because it could return true on incorrectly sized grids so don't use this, I just want to demonstrate the syntax.)

You could make a function to pattern match the lists in sets of 3:

```
let streakExists grid =
    let checkListOf3 list =
        match list with
        |[Marker.X; Marker.X; Marker.X] -> true
        |_ -> false
    if grid.[0..2] |> checkListOf3 then true
    elif grid.[3..5] |> checkListOf3 then true
    elif grid.[6..8] |> checkListOf3 then true
     ...
    else false
```

**Edit**

You could combine this last approach with the one suggested by Tomas using his `streaks` to create:

```
let streakExists grid =
    let checkListOf3 list =
        match list with
        |[Marker.X; Marker.X; Marker.X] -> true
        |_ -> false
    streaks |> List.exists (List.map (fun i -> List.item i grid) >> checkListOf3)
```